# Implicit initialization of aggregate subpbject

Tags: c, struct, initialization, aggregate, language-lawyer

When looking at the initialization rules for aggregates in the N2310 I found the following paragraphs (emp. mine):

`6.7.9(p19)`:

> The initialization shall occur in initializer list order, each
>   initializer provided for a particular subobject overriding any
>   previously listed initializer for the same subobject; 154) **all**
>   **subobjects that are not initialized explicitly shall be initialized**
>   **implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration.**

`6.7.9(p21)`:

> If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there
>   are elements or members of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a
>   string literal used to initialize an array of known size than there
>   are elements in the array, **the remainder of the aggregate shall be**
>   **initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage**
>   **duration**.

It seems to me that `6.7.9(p19)` implies `6.7.9(p21)` (but not wise versa). For instance:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct test{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

int main(){
    struct test test = {
        .a = 123
    };

    printf("%d%d%d\n", test.a, test.b, test.c); //obviously, 12300 is printed
}
```

I think this case can be explained by both `6.7.9(p19)` and `6.7.9(p21)`

What is the purpose of `6.7.9(p21)`? What did I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

6.7.9 takes into account the so-called designated initializers.

Consider the following demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct test{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

int main(void) 
{
    struct test test = {
        .c = 123
    };

    printf("%d %d %d\n", test.a, test.b, test.c);

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
0 0 123
```

Or another program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 10 };
    int a[N] = { [0] = 0, [4] = 4, [9] = 9 };

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
0 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 9
```

So

> **all subobjects that are not initialized explicitly shall be
>   initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage
>   duration**.

The second quote existed before the designated initializers were adopted in the C Standard and describes the situation like for example this

```
char s[20] = "Hello";
```

and answers the question whether the tail of the character array will be initialized. It keeps the compatibility with the C++ Standard where the designated initializers were absent until the C++ 17 Standard.

Comment: "the designated initializers were absent until the C++ 17 Standard."  Is C++20 intended instead of C++17?

Comment: @L.F. They are described in the C++ 17 Standard Draft.

Comment: If I understand you correcrly, the point is that the second quote is not concerned about the `initializer-list`, but the first is. Right?

Comment: @SomeName No the both quotes deal with initializer list. But the first quote describes situations when elements of an aggregate have no explicit initializer between two or before one designated initializer. The second quote descrines situation when there is no gap between initialized data members but there is no enough initializers for all elements.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Understood, thanks. Just to clarify, in case we mix disiganted and non-designated initializers like [in this example](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4ad0bbd2e2ea435a) we also use the first quote, correct?

Comment: @SomeName In this case the both quotes are applyed.

Comment: Ah, the first quote contained the description of how to initialize in case of gaps in the initializer list... as you mentioned in your second example. The quote's wording is misleading anyway...

Comment: Designated initializers in C++17?  Can you show the relevant part of the standard?  As far as I remember, they are part of the big C++20 update :-/

Comment: @L.F. From the C++ 17 Standard Draft: braced-init-list:
{ initializer-list ,opt }
{ designated-initializer-list ,opt }
{ }

Comment: @VladfromMoscow That's not what I see.  I only see "braced-init-list:
 { initializer-list ,opt }
 { }" in [\[dcl.init\]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init#nt:braced-init-list).

Comment: @L.F. Document Number: N4713
Date: 2017-11-27
Revises: N4700

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Hmm ...  the C++17 final draft is N4659, not N4713 or N4700.  Anything after that belongs to the C++20 timeline, even if the year 2017 didn't end yet.

Comment: @L.F. I have no the final Draft.:)

Comment: The final draft (N4659) is publicly accessible, and it differs from the actual standard only in page numbers and in that it is not “known to be incomplet and incorrekt” etc :-)